# Saving and Restoring the Data for a Calendar Application on Android

Tags: java, android, calendar

I am programming an application which makes use of the internal calendars of the Android. The application is a kind of an "agenda" for a specific pourpose.

I need to be able to mark on the Calendar with a different color that a certain day has some Event marked on it. I can do this no problem, the question is, when I shut down the application, these colors on my Calendar View are lost.

So I need to find a way to store the data about the days which have been marked with specific events. I've thought of 2 approaches: One is to save the data of ALL Events marked in my App into the Internal Storage or SQLite Databases, or I've thought of looping through the WHOLE calendar and look for which events belong to my App. This second approach seems to me to be very slow, since it's also hard to define the upper and lower limits of the cycle.

What are the propositions? Is there another better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app is independent of the user's calendar events, you could create a `SyncAdapter` (which requires an `AccountAuthenticator` as well), and register it to sync with the android calendar stuff. Then, as a sync adapter, create a new calendar with the color your want and mark it as read-only; put your events in there and they will appear on any calendar apps the user might use. From your app, just query the events within your calendar, and you get your events without additional filtering.

---

**Examples and Articles:** there's the [android doc about the calendar provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html), which describes how to access and modify calendars and events. You need that to create and fill your calendar. If you don't need authentification for your application, see ["Creating a Stub Authenticator"](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-authenticator.html), and create accounts programatically via

```
Account account = new Account("static username, displayed to user", "your.type");
AccountManager.get(context).addAccountExplicitly(account, "", null);
ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(account, "com.android.calendar", true);
```

Remember to register your sync adapter with a separate xml file (res/xml/yourname.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sync-adapter xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:contentAuthority="com.android.calendar"
              android:accountType="your.type"
              android:userVisible="true"
              android:allowParallelSyncs="false"
              android:isAlwaysSyncable="true"
              android:supportsUploading="false"
/>
```

Note that I added `isAlwaysSyncable`; when not setting that attribute, `ContentResolver.setIsSyncable` must get called to allow any syncs.

You also need to register a service producing your SyncAdapter (just as with `AccountAuthenticator`), in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<service android:name=".package.classname" android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" android:resource="@xml/yourname" />
</service>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
<!-- when distributing an AccountAuthenticator this is also required: -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
```

For the general sync adapter stuff and on how to put it together, there's a great blog post ["write your own Android Sync Adapter"](http://udinic.wordpress.com/2013/07/24/write-your-own-android-sync-adapter/).

Comment: thanks dst! And by turning them read-only, will I be able to change them Inside my application? I don't want to allow them to be changed outside my app, because it may contain important info that cannot be changed outside.

Comment: You can sync read-only calendars. I'm not completely sure if you can change it from anywhere within your application, but from the sync adapter it should work.

Comment: I am a bit rookie with the CalendarProvider but this seems to be a great idea. Actually I was planning on doing this but due to the lack of experience I have been using one of the existing calendars for storing my events. Do you know any website or article which illustrates in more detail this solution you've posted? Thanks a lot

Comment: Adde some stuff, I hope that's enough to get you started ;)

Comment: I know how to add and delete events from an existing calendar. What is confusing me with your solution is the fact that I need to create some kind of Sync Adapter, which has Accounts connected to it, when I don't need any authentication for my App. All I want is to store events on a Calendar and have them present every time I start my App. What you are telling me is that to this I need all this stuff of SyncAdapter?

Comment: If your app wants to control an calendar, it must provide an `Authentificator`, as you are only allowed to write an calendar's [CALENDAR_ACCESS_LEVEL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.CalendarColumns.html#CALENDAR_ACCESS_LEVEL) when accessing from a `SyncAdapter`. You could try to generate the sync adapter Uris and create your calendar without all that, however I don't think that's a good style not following the Android docs.